# jQuery and val() undefined on ASP.NET using Visual Studio

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I tried using this code to obtain the var value using jQuery. For some reason name equals null or undefined, and I can't seem to figure it out.

```
<asp:TextBox 
    ID="Text_Email" 
    runat="server" 
    CssClass="" 
    Width="234px">Email</asp:TextBox>

var name = $("#<%=Text_Email.ClientID%>").value; // name == undefined
```

Here is my main script:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#<%=send_info.ClientID%>").click(function () {
        // var name = document.getElementById("#<%=Text_Name.ClientID%>").value;
        var name = $("#<%=Text_Email.ClientID%>").value;
        var reg = /^([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])+\@([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])+\.([A-Za-z]{2,4})$/;

         if (reg.test(name) == false) {
             $(this).val("");
             $("#error_email_adress").removeClass('email_valid');
             $("#error_email_adress").addClass('email_invalid');
             return false;
         } else {
             $("#error_email_adress").removeClass('email_invalid');
             $("#error_email_adress").addClass('email_valid');
             alert("Message sent");
             return true;
         }
     });
 });
```

This part also confuses me. Why does this occur? Can someone explain to me why name is defined here?

```
$("#<%=Text_Email.ClientID%>").click(function () {
    var name = this.value;//name != undefined;
});
```

whereas here name is undefined

```
var name = $("#<%=Text_Email.ClientID%>").value; // name == undefined;
```

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

jQuery does not have value but val() function for textbox,

Try this,

```
var name = $("#<%=Text_Email.ClientID%>").val();
```

Your code will be

```
$("#<%=Text_Email.ClientID%>").click(function () {
       var name = $(this).val();// you will get value in name by this statement.
});
```

Comment: I tried it just a really long load and ends up not passing through the next line.

Comment: Corrected and updated answer epascarello, thanks for pointing it.

Comment: var name = $("#<%=Text_Email.ClientID%>").val(); for some reason jquery unable to move next line

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead of what you've written

```
$(this).val()
```

Note that jquery's syntax is almost straightforward.The function concerning the value of an element is $.val() , you can set an element's value by passing it a string like :

```
$(this).val("the desired value");
```

or you can get the element's value by not passing it anything.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#<%=Text_Email.ClientID%>").click(function () {
    var name = this.value;  //<-- 'this' here is a DOM HTML Object which has .value property
    var elem = jQuery(this); //<-- converts the DOM Object into a jQuery object, jQuery does not have .value property
    var nameVal = elem.val(); //<-- get the value the jQuery way
});
```

Reading material:

- [jQuery .val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/)